# Return binary data via RFC

Tags: abap, saprfc, pyrfc

I want to return binary data in ABAP, for example a [PNG](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) image file.

Which data type should I use? string, xstring, ...?

I use the PyRFC SDK: https://github.com/SAP/PyRFC

Comment: In ABAP, bytes are to be stored in variables of type X or XSTRING. But the answer may vary depending on the RFC SDK you use (with NCO, XSTRING variables are mapped to STRING C# variables with hexadecimal format, knowing that it's more interesting to pass bytes in base64 strings!)

Comment: We are currently investigating GetByteArray in NCO, if it works then XSTRING are supported nicely even in NCO. If I understand well pyRFC, it's based on the API from NWRFCSDK, thus RfcGetBytes should do the job too. Answer: XSTRING. But that's simply a guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `xstring`

*Sidenotes if you have large data:*

- max size of an xstring is 2GB (depending also on profile parameter `ztta/max_memreq_MB`)
- If you use an internal table of xstrings (e.g. dictionary type `XSTRINGS_TABLE`), dynamic memory allocation is easier because it will not be requested in one go, as is the case for a flat xstring

Comment: Is rawstring the same?

Comment: Yes, `RAWSTRING` is the dictionary built-in type which maps to the `XSTRING` ABAP built-in type

Comment: For PyRFC it's good. Beware that some external systems wouldn't be able to receive it. we tried a lot with informatica without success.